# Hyperledger Fabric Fabcar error for enrolladmin.js

Tags: node.js

I have started the fabric script and after that I run the enrolladmin.js file.

`node enrolladmin.js`

but got the following error. How to resolve it?

```
node enrollAdmin.js
fs.js:904
return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/jaspalsingh/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaspalsingh/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:37:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaspalsingh/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:38:12)
```

Comment: More context of your enrolladmin script would be helpful to help with that problem. It looks somewhat like some binaries are missing that would be downloaded in some step before that you might have missed - but that is wild guessing :-)

Comment: I am trying to run fabcar example under fabric-samples folder which I downloaded from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html#how-does-it-work

Comment: now I am following instructions step by step ... npm install ... fabric start script run... next step is to enrol the admin .. while running this file giving methe above error. not able to resolve ny help would be of great use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. just resolved it by these steps:

1. Create directory : < FABCAR_DIR>/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/
2. Do "npm install" in < FABCAR_DIR>
3. Do "npm rebuild" in < FABCAR_DIR>

step 2 or 3 - one of them should solve the problem - try in the same order.

After step 2 OR step 3 - you should see a file.
< FABCAR_DIR>/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v46-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node

After that enroll admin should succeed like:

```
sprint @ fabcar>node enrollAdmin.js
 Store path:/home/ravir/hl/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"
Assigned the admin user to the fabric client ::{"name":"admin","mspid":"Org1MSP","roles":null,"affiliation":"","enrollmentSecret":"","enrollment":{"signingIdentity":"42d8536072cf7e47358c137b254d78d8e853934caee70d03dbec06a22f482ad9","identity":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\}
```

if u look closely, the output of startFabric.sh prints

"

```
Start by installing required packages run 'npm install'
Then run 'node enrollAdmin.js', then 'node registerUser'
```

"

Comment: thanks a ton .. it resolved my problem ... please explain the logic behind this setting ..

Comment: Glad it worked... the steps required me to run "npm install" before "./startFabric.sh" - i think it errored out and i did NOT see this msg:"[grpc] Success: "/home/ravir/hl/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v46-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote                                                                                                                                                              "  -- this is what was missing and resulted in error - so "npm rebuild" or re-running "npm install" will have built this dependency... HTH

Comment: @JaspalSingh, can u pls mark this the correct answer ? Thx

Comment: actually, after running ur network with th script file, u have to install NPM (node packet modules), after running                                                       
$./startFabric.sh                                                                                            $npm install -g (-g => installs node modules globally, so u don't have to create any kind of directories!)